# TexMaker/TexStudio manual invocation of auto-completition

Tags: texmaker, texstudio, auto-completion

I have started using TexStudio and TexMaker (as I think they are quite similar) but I have failed to find in the scarce documentation there is available (and a brief online searching) a shortcut that manually invokes auto-completion function. I am not talking about manually "adding" something to it; just invoking it.

(I am talking about the functionality provided in Eclipse with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, Vim <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and so on...)

If anyone knows where is this hiding please let me know.

Comment: Just use the standard "Esc" shortcut on a word to invoke auto-completion. Texmaker and Texstudio are completely different : they don't use the same editor component, the same pdf viewer and the syntax for the commands are different (Texstudio is only cloning the look and feel of Texmaker.)

Comment: In TeXstudio, use Ctrl+Space.

Comment: Well I was accustomed to VIM for writing my LaTEX documents, but now I tried to evaluate these editors since I heard quite good feedback for both of them. The auto-completion of VIM was invokable more proactively in my experience but anyway I'll try and evaluate them a bit more.

Thanks for your input @TimHoffmann

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by user27168, typing <kbd>Esc</kbd> invokes auto-completion in TeXmaker and (as pointed out by Tim Hoffmann) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> invoke that in TeXstudio.